# Automatically display value in a text box based on the value entered in another text box using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 text boxes namely `textbox1`, `textbox2` and `textbox3`.

If i enter a numeric value to `textbox1`, then automatically `textbox2` and `textbox3` should display the values `textbox1*25` and `textbox*75` respectively.

Textbox2 and `textbox3` should not be editable and it should be in display mode.

Can anyone help me in finding the solution using javascript.

Thanks in advance,
Amith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though, we are not a codefactory try this: [myExample](http://jsfiddle.net/Usdut/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onblur` event to check if the input's value is a number using a regular expression. Assign the other input attributes with the same multiplied by 25,75 and set the `readOnly` value to true.

And do elaborate on what you mean by "Display Mode".

Here is a [working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/m7LnF/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You need an id in the three elements like id="textbox1", in the textbox1 element, you need an event like onChange="my_func()" so every time you change the value, it jumps to the function:

Then you need the javascript function like:

```
<script>
function my_func() {
    document.getElementById("textbox2").innerHTML=document.getElementById("textbox1").value*25;
    document.getElementById("textbox3").innerHTML=document.getElementById("textbox1").value*75;
}
</script>
```